# How common is it for environmentally occurring bacillus strain to contain some sort of plasmid?

Tags: microbiology, molecular-genetics, environment

I am designing a method for testing whether two new bacillus isolates, that are ionic silver resistant, store the silver resistance mechanism on a plasmid or on the chromosome of the bacteria.

In my method, after I do a plasmid extraction on the bacteria, I want to use nanodrop to see if plasmids are even present in the bacteria (if no plasmids are found, then the silver resistance mechanism must be stored chromosomally). After this, I want to use heat shock or electroporation to place the plasmid in a silver sensitive bacteria, and see if the newly transformed bacteria is ionic silver resistant (this would suggest the resistance mechanism is stored on the plasmid)

I have been looking at how other people have tested for this, and I have found that the nanodrop part is not done. I thought the nanodrop would be a good control to make sure the plasmid extraction went well, and if plasmid DNA was not found, it would save me from doing the rest of the experiment.

One reason why I thought they didn't do nanodrop was that perhaps most environmentally occurring bacillus contain plasmids, and thus nanodrop would be unnecessary step.

So my question becomes how common is it for environmentally occurring bacillus strain to contain some sort of plasmid? Also, if anybody has any suggestions for improvment of my method, please let me know.